# Run into error while executing react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, react-native, build-error

Hi I have created a project using react-native and when I run the command

`react-native run-ios`

the build fails in the terminal with the following error:

```
**The following build commands failed:**

CompileC /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/albums-gnnqffkyfazehwcywcchxrdqkvpd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCTBaseTextInputView.o /ReactNative/albums/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/TextInput/RCTBaseTextInputView.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Comment: did you run `pod install` beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd ios
pod install
react-native run-ios
```

You can run your react native IOS app using XCode  by following below steps:

1.Go to your App folder, then go to ios folder. You'll see a file named AwesomeProject.xcworkspace.

2.Open this file and it will open your App in Xcode.

3.Select the desired simulator and click the ▶️ button to run your App.

Comment: I did the steps still the problem persists. Even I ran from the xcode the simulator shows

No Bundle URL Present. Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle in your application bundle.

Now I can see a main.jsbundle but it is not opened or can I find it in Finder.

Kindly help. I just created a app and beginning this error